# Which nations have armed prisoners and sent them to war?

Tags: war

I'm looking for examples of countries that have **armed** prisoners and sent them to war? Were the prisoners coerced, or were they offered amnesty should they survive?

Comment: Mark C. Wallace, I am actually asking for notable examples, so that I an look them up. If you can edit the heading, go on!

Comment: Generally the site discourages questions that are answered by lists of examples.

Comment: Wasn't there something about the ancient Chinese sending armies of convicts into battle, where the first row would be beheaded in front of the enemy as a demoralizing tactic?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that *often* is subjective.
Here are some examples from World War II:

- [Strafbattalions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafbattalion) in Nazi Germany were created from prisoners
- [Dirlewanger Brigade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36th_Waffen_Grenadier_Division_of_the_SS) in Nazi Germany was originally formed for anti-partisan actions, but took part in war battles, later.
- [Shtrafbats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtrafbat), in the Soviet Union, were created mostly from courted privates and officers for Red Army.

[The Wikipedia article on Penal military units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_military_unit) links to other examples.

In the Soviet Union [Order No. 227](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_No._227), soldiers and officers convicted of cowardice and/or disciplinary problems were assigned to penal battalions. Penal battalions were sent to the most dangerous sections of the front lines. There was a possibility to achieve amnesty through outstanding military service, though no amnesty was guaranteed.

Relevant parts of the order:

> The Supreme General Headquarters of the Red Army commands:
>   ...
>   Form within each Front from one up to three (depending on the situation) penal battalions (800 persons) where commanders and high commanders and appropriate commissars of all service arms who have been guilty of a breach of discipline due to cowardice or bewilderment will be sent, and put them on more difficult sectors of the front to give them an opportunity to redeem by blood their crimes against the Motherland.
>   ...
>   Form within the limits of each army up to ten (depending on the situation) penal companies (from 150 to 200 persons in each) where ordinary soldiers and low-ranking commanders who have been guilty of a breach of discipline due to cowardice or bewilderment will be routed, and put them at difficult sectors of the army to give them an opportunity to redeem by blood their crimes against the Motherland.

I have no information about amnesty for Nazi soldiers.

Comment: I think amnesty was guaranteed if a person was wounded. For regular criminals a month in penal unit counted as a year in prison.

Comment: @Anixx, it's interesting. Could you provide some links?

Comment: do mind that the regime in the penal units was harsh enough they were unlikely to survive a month, effectively they were forced into battle as cannonfodder, the rifles and bayonets of their guards and political officers in their backs. Any who was too slow, seemed to falter, or dared to turn back in a hopeless situation was killed. So there were no wounded...

Comment: @jwenting I assume it's an answer for Anixx's comment. I have to say that I agree that regime in penal units was extremely harsh and mortality rate (is it a suitable term?) was very high. But considering shtrafbats, I found [references](http://grachev62.narod.ru/stalin/t18/t18_269.htm) in support of amnesty for hospitalized soldiers. I don't have any statistic on number of such occasions, though (at least [one example](http://goo.gl/edCQ1) from quick google search). Also, "wounded" and "turning back in hopeless situations" are different categories.

Comment: @defaultlocale not really. If you had an arm shot off you were supposed to press on even if you died, rather than call for a medic to be evacuated... Maybe if you survived to the end of an action and were wounded, yes you might get pardoned or transferred to rear area duties.

Comment: @jwenting agreed. My point was that `there were no wounded...` line sounded too absolutist to me.

Comment: @jwenting Of course there were plenty of wounded in penal units.

Comment: @jwenting is there a citation for the "no medic, go on even if you're bleeding to death"?

Comment: @defaultlocale, I believe the example you pointed to was an exception rather than the rule. There are quite a few witnesses quoted by various sources that the amnesty for prisoners promised by Red Army was a sham: the prisoner would get pardoned if he would perform 10 dangerous missions, such as unprotected tail gunner on Il-2 or a mine field sweeper, and if the prisoner would miraculously survive 9 missions he would be re-assigned and never get sent to the 10th mission.

Comment: @Michael, well, I just pointed to the document that guarantees amnesty for wounded soldiers. I've never heard anything about "10 dangerous missions". Would you be so kind to provide references for this part?

Comment: @defaultlocale: I couldn't locate the link in a few min, and now have to go. Maybe you have a better luck, if you are interested. It make have been from Solzhenitsin, or from another author who collected prisoners' stories of those times. There were basically two story lines told by many 1st hand witnesses: the promise of amnesty for 10 missions as the rear Il-2 gunner (unprotected, 8x death rate compared with Il-2 pilots), and the promise of amnesty for 10 mine field clearing missions. About amnesty for being wounded: the 1st time I've heard about that is your question.

Comment: @Anixx: amnesty was promised for a variety of deeds, but more often than not undelivered, one way or another. I've heard from a few sources that amnesty was promised for performing 10 specific exceptionally dangerous missions, where most prisoners got killed before approaching the 10th mission, such as clearing mines or flying as unprotected IL-2 gunner (in early IL-2 versions where gunner had no protection at all). However, when a prisoner was lucky enough to complete 9 of the 10 missions he was no longer sent to them and reassigned instead to other duties, so that he wouldn't complete 10.

Comment: @Michael you are describing some US-like approach that would be simply impossible in the USSR. There was no "mission mentality" in Soviet tactics (it is mostly US thing), and no one would count "missions". There were fights, battles,... no "missions", especially in so low-level units as penal ones. The conditions to be moved from penal units were usually some time spent there and/or receiving a wound (this would be called "paying with blood"). All you wrote is simple fantasy.

Comment: @default locale evidently, he just invented it or repeats fantasy of someone with computer games experience only.

Comment: @Anixx: what I have wrote is based on the testimony of soviet prisoners who served as described. Sorry, too busy at work to search for sources.

Comment: @Anixx just fyi, the Wikipedia page default locale linked in his answer also uses the "mission" vocabulary, but only in the air force, where it actually makes sense (mission=from takeoff to landing)

Comment: *the testimony of soviet prisoners who served as described.* So, there were some that survived?

Comment: I would suggest that while sometimes they used criminals because they could find no one else in the case of the soldiers under Dirlewanger it was useful to have criminals (indeed Dirlewanger himself was a sex criminal) to do the sort of terrible things they were tasked with doing.

Answer (score 15):

[The French Foreign Legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Foreign_Legion) was originally a fighting force made up of criminals and other undesirables.

> The purpose of the Foreign Legion was to remove disruptive elements from society and put them to use fighting the enemies of France. Recruits included failed revolutionaries from the rest of Europe, soldiers from the disbanded Swiss and German mercenary regiments of the Bourbon monarchy, and troublemakers in general, both foreign and French.

Comment: yes, but they weren't convicts (unless an escaped prisoner were to apply, in which case the Legion Estranger will not care, they don't ask for your history or even proof of identity on enlistment, or didn't use to, it may have changed).

Comment: @jwenting "Etrangere" in French. And you are correct, today they go as far as checking with your home country and interpol that you aren't wanted. Also things have changed in general, while they welcome tough people from rough places, things like a past of drug use/dealing, violent assault etc automatically disqualify you today.

Answer (score 12):

In ancient times some states would in times of extreme adversity arm their slaves and promise hem freedom if they acquitted themselves well in the fight.

[For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achaean_League):

> However by the time of the Achaean war in the 140s BC, the League's
>   army had decreased in strength and efficiency. The League was even
>   reduced to freeing and arming 12,000 slaves.

Comment: the Confederacy during the US civil war did the same thing.

Comment: The Union did the same with Confederate prisoners but only to fight Indians.

Comment: @ExpatEgghead During or after the Civil War?

Comment: During as far as I know. The best source I have is the book'Gone With The Wind' and the character George Ashley Wilkes who had this offer made to him and refused thus keeping him in  Rock Island Arsenal.

Comment: http://www.archives.gov/research/military/civil-war/galvanized-yankees.pdf  Interesting term - galvanized yankees

Answer (score 10):

"Prisoners" fall into two categories. The first is  military men court-martialed for cowardice, or other offenses, that are given a chance to redeem themselves. The second is criminals sent to war.

The first kind of prisoners were quite common particularly in totalitarian societies such as Nazi Germany or the Soviet Union (e.g. in World War II).

The second type was less common, but used from time to time. By definition, criminals are aggressive people suited to fighting, and who need a chance to redeem themselves.

Sometimes the "amnesty" was offered before the criminals were caught. The British (and other countries) did this in the 17th and 18th century with pirates. Provided that they agreed not to attack ships of their own country, such people were given letters of pardon that immunized them from punishment for attacking the ships of OTHER countries. That process turned "pirates" into "privateers."

Comment: +1 for categorization. But `criminals are aggressive people suited to war` line sounds weird for me. Regular army assumes discipline and organization. I think personal aggressiveness is a negative factor here.

Comment: I believe the British Navy in the early 1800's was comprised of some men who were convicts, not sure about the land armies under Wellington but I recall some historical novels that often referred to men who might have gone to jail but went to serve.

Comment: How number of court-materialed soldiers corresponds to totalitarity of state? I think it only corresponds to the magnitude of hostilities. -1

Comment: Concur that criminals are not by definition aggressive people suited to war.  None of the clauses in that sentence are defensible.  War demands disciple more than aggression, and "criminal" can include people whose behavior or opinions differ from that of the local government.   (Are Nelson Mandela, Ghandi or Martin Luther King intrinsically excellent warriors merely because they were convicted?). Nor do they automatically need redemption.   Rest of the answer is excellent.

Comment: +1, default locale, you can see a good example how it worked at "The Dirty Dozen" movie. :)

Comment: @Anixx: The "classic" was Stalin's purge of Tugachevsky et. al. during PEACETIME (no hostilities). It made Hitler's "purge" of generals after the assassination attempt in 1944 look "selective" by comparison.

Comment: @Tom Au Tachachevsky was not a soldier.

Comment: Tugachevsky was an OFFICER (a Marshal). But the question was about "prisoners," not "soldiers." Following the 1938 purge, Rokossovsky was taken out of a Siberian prison to command an army group in World War II.

Comment: @Tom Au you claimed that the number of court-martialed solders correspond to the totalitarity of a state and cite a repressed marshal to support your words. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 9):

I know it has been common practice in the USA in the past to send convicted criminals to serve in the military in time of war in lieu of jail or some other kind of community service. Particularly during WWII, when [thousands of men were paroled](http://encompass.eku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1081&context=etd) contingent on military service.

During the unit self-intro bit at the beginning of [Stripes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083131/), I believe at least one recruit had been sent by a judge. That is high fiction of course, but I know of a least one reference in non-fiction: In the opening chapters of [Hill 488](http://www.hill488.com/) Ray Hildreth relates being given a choice of jail or military service after some "youthful indiscretions"

This is cheifly something that was done back when there was a draft (and thus men of fighting age would have been at a premium), not something done today with the USA's all-volunteer armed forces. So the reference in Stripes was probably an anachronisim. Today the USA armed forces generally do not even accept convicted (violent) felons. For example, the [current Army regs](http://www.apd.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/pdf/web/r601-210_Web_FINAL.pdf)<sup>(pdf)</sup> on this require a waiver for a lot of criminal offenses, and a lot more cannot be waived.

Comment: BTW: Hill 488 is a whale of a read. Sort of like Rorke's Drift in Vietnam.

Comment: I don't know how common it is or was in the US, but I remember during MEPS being asked a question along the lines of: Did a judge order you to join the service? I want to say it was on one of the forms I had to fill out but it could have just been something I was asked. It made me think that joining the service instead of being sentenced for a crime is/was fairly common at one point in time.

Comment: they were not prisoners. For specific non-violent crimes people'd be offered the choice of prison or enlistment in the armed forces.

Comment: @T.E.D. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hill_488) alone is good. The statement of SGT Howard about LCpl Bins which was used for his MoH had me rapt.

Comment: Two of the sailors who served with me in the 1980's were given an option by the judge: join the military or accept the court's punishment. (Both were misdemeanor cases, not felony.)  They were both good sailors, I might add.

Comment: Please cite all nontrivial assertions.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I had better luck finding some references today than I did when I looked 5 years ago. Link has been added. However I did also find that there's a surprising dearth of hard data on this subject after WWII, simultaneous with an almost unimpeachable amount of anecdotal evidence of the practice. Perhaps that's because the Army has lately tried to discourage it. I could see where it wouldn't be good for recruiting to be known for this.

Comment: I read in Dan Fante's autobiography of a friend of his caught siphoning gasoline who was given choice between military and prison. This was mid 1960s so military meant Vietnam -- not sure which I would have chosen except that Vietnam would allow you to avoid a record.

Answer (score 9):

The British army has sent convicts to war, perhaps most notably during the time of Wellington and the Peninsular War. Convicted criminals could choose between prison/execution or joining the army. An army of such men lead Wellington to describe them as "The scum of the earth" after the looting that occurred following the battle of Vitoria.

Comment: Wellington (when he was still General Wellesley) is reputed to have said - during the Peninsula War "I don't know what effect these men will have upon the enemy, but by God they frighten me". Nelson's navy was also made up of a lot of convicts, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

A large part of the French "Black Legion" under the American Colonel Tate, which invaded Wales in February 1797, was made up of convicts. An action referred to as "a singular expedition of jail birds" by French author Captain Desbriere.

The plan of attack was devised by General Lazare Hoche, who had also conceived a similarly ill-fated attack on Ireland a couple of months earlier. The idea was that a small force would be landed in a relatively unprotected part of the British Isles. They could then use a form of guerilla warfare to cause damage out of proportion to their small number and provoke a lower-class revolt.

> Hoche credited Carnot with the first idea of organizing a *chouannerie* or system of guerilla warfare in England, for the purpose of giving the inhabitants freedom and inducing them to adopt a
>   republican form of government. With this object in view, the invaders,
>   recruited from the galleys and prisons, and promised full enjoyment of
>   their booty, immunity from their crimes, and a remission of all past
>   sentences, were to proclaim themselves the "avengers of liberty and
>   enemies of tyrants"...as they advanced they were to throw open the
>   prisons and replenish their ranks by a fresh supply of indigenous
>   malefactors
>
> <sup>*Napoleon and the Invasion of England, Vol 1*, Wheeler & Broadley (London, 1907), pg 38</sup>

Hoche himself described the force, raised in secret, in a letter to the Directorate, on the 11th December 1796...

> It is composed of six hundred men from all the prisons in my district, and they are collected in two forts or islands to obviate the possibility of escape. I associate with them six hundred picked convicts from the galleys, still wearing their irons.

Irishman Wolfe Tone had seen this force, whilst in France, and described them

> I have witnessed a review of the Black Legion, about 1800 strong. These are the bandits destined for England, and are unmitigated blackguards.

As Wheeler & Broadley rightly noted, "No plan was assuredly ever conceived more entirely calculated to defeat its own object".

In the event, the force that landed near Fishguard, on 22nd February 1797, consisted of around 1,400 men (with no artillery or cavalry). After a brief stand-off with the local militia force, the French surrendered without a fight on the 24th February, having shown little intention of doing anything else.

Answer (score 6):

During World War II, the Germans captured quite a number of Soviet troops who were from the far eastern, Asiatic regions of the Soviet Union.  The Germans pressed some of these Soviet Asiatic prisoners into service in the German Army, particularly to fill out low-quality static, positional defense units.  The Allies captured some of these troops in Normandy in 1944.  There is an amazing but true story of a Korean man who was forced to serve in the Japanese Army.  He was captured during one of the Soviet vs. Japanese fights that took place shortly prior to World War II breaking out globally.  The Soviets offered him the opportunity to serve in the Soviet Army and he took it.  Later, he was captured by the Germans and forced to serve in the German Army until he was taken prisoner by the Western Allies.

Answer (score 6):

My father reported that approximately 30 of 130 men in his RAF squadron (247 China British) were former inmates of HM Prisons who were allowed to enlist for the duration of WW2 and would not have to return to complete their sentence. I have recorded this in Nash, John C., ''Across an Ocean and Time: The World as Seen by Harry Nash'', Ottawa, Canada: Nash Information Services Inc., 2010.  ISBN 0-88769-013-0. Available freely at https://archive.org/details/AcrossAnOceanAndTime_201411}.

I have not, unfortunately, so far discovered documentation of this program, which I would, of course, welcome.

Answer (score 4):

France, in the late 1940's, had a part of their colonial army made up of German prisoners of war and French collaborationists, taken from prisons and prisoner of war camps.  It was called the [Overseas Light Infantry Battalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataillon_d%27Infanterie_l%C3%A9g%C3%A8re_d%27Outre-Mer).  It was similar to the [Battalions of Light Infantry of Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battalions_of_Light_Infantry_of_Africa), though I think the latter was almost all released prisoners who had not regained their civil rights.

Answer (score 2):

One should add to the accepted answer that besides "regular" criminals as well as  "soldiers and officers convicted of cowardice or/and common crimes", **some** political prisoners were also sent to serve in the Red Army during WWII. One of the most prominent examples is [Konstantin Rokossovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Rokossovsky) who went from a political prisoner to one of the most important Soviet military commanders.

Comment: Indeed. His memoir begins with the phrase how he went to a sanatorium for rest and recuperation and then took up his command. The sanatorium was necessary because he was in a very bad condition upon release from the gulag camp but he was not allowed to write about that.

Answer (score 2):

The American/Canadian First Special Services Force of WWII -- the Canadians sent their best volunteers, the US Army emptied their brigs. Intended to perform special operations in Norway and Sweden, they were trained in parachuting, skiing, amphibious operations, and close combat. Instead, they landed in the Aleutians -- after the Japanese had left -- and served in Italy, where their assault of Monte la Difensa practically ended the unit as a fighting force.

> As a practical matter, many post commanders seized this opportunity to empty their stockades and rid themselves of hard-case troublemakers in all categories. Prisoners frequently were given the option of continuing their sentences or 'volunteering' for Frederick's Force.

Source: "The Devil's Brigade", Robert Adelman and George Walton. p 47 (Kindle Edition)

Frederick, the unit commander, wrote a memo in which he said:

> From one post I received a telegram that said, 'All volunteers for your command have departed this date. Direct the officer in charge and armed guards to return to this station as soon as practicable.

From another:

> All personnel transferred to your command are en route except 42 AWOL, 26 men sick not in line of duty and requiring further treatment, and 14 men in confinement awaiting final action on remission of sentences. These volunteers for your command will be transferred as soon as available.

(ibid)

On page 59 of the same book, the process by which Canadian members were chosen is discussed:

> there were approximately 85 of us who signed up, but after taking medical and IQ tests there were only 26 left. Then Colonel Williams talked to us and advised anyone that was married to drop out as the Force was likely to have a short but lively life. I believe we ended up with sixteen men who went to Helena for training.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Prussian Marshal Blucher, although born in the territory of Mecklenburg in Germany began his military career by enlisting in the Swedish army, in the Hussars in 1758. He was captured by the Prussians in 1760 during the Seven Years War and accepted the opportunity to switch sides and serve in the Prussian army, which he continued to do, on and off, for more than 50 years thereafter, playing an important part in the Napoleonic Wars including in Napoleon's final defeat at Waterloo in 1815.

I do not know if that was common in those days, but other members of his family enlisted in the Danish or Prussian armies, so it seems there was flexibility about such matters then.

I also read somewhere of an occasion in 1919 during the Russian Civil War when 'Red' (Communist/Bolshevik) troops captured by the anti-communist Whites were formed up in line, saw their officers shot in front of them, and were then told that any of them who wanted to volunteer to serve in the White army should step forward. They were not actually told what would happen to any who refused, but being able to guess, they all stepped forward.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing a book on a the extraordinary life of Ralph Emerson Lee.  Lee's criminal record began in 1910 at age 15 until 1946.  There are newspaper accounts (do not know yet if the accounts are TRUE.) of him being released from the Az. State Prison in 1918 to serve in the army.  He was supposedly released at the end of WWI with an Honorable Discharge:*

*Franklin Evening Star " (Franklin, Indiana) 25 Sept 1924, page 6
"...he (Lee) was sentenced to the Arizona peniteniary.  He was confined there until the outbreak of WWI.  When the war started, Arizona had a ruling that permitted the release of all young prisoners who would promise to enter the service overseas and Lee availed himself of this opportunity.  He went to France and served with credit and at the end of the war, received an honorable discharge."

Despite deep digging I have not been able to substantiate this. The man was a gifted artist and could have forged the discharge document.

"Stories of the Great War for Public Speakers" by William Herbert Brown, page 200:
     "The Oregon State Penitentiary officials were proud of a service flag in that insitution which contained forty stars when the great war closed, representing forty prisoners who had been paroled to enlist in the U.S. army or navy.  They made good to such an extent that nearly every one of them was restored to citizenship by the Governor of Oregon."

If one googles the current situation in our military branches of service one will find numerous articles that because of the enlistment crisis--men are being offered service in the military as an alternative to jail.  Each branch of our military has a "waiver" system where a prisoner can opt out of jail and serve in the military.  One of many examples:

www.salon.com/2006/02/02/waivers/

Above is the link to one such article. Appeared in Salon magazine, Feb 2, 2006:

**Would appreciate any and all referenced sources about the state of Arizona releasing young prisoners to serve overseas in WWI**